# assosiate two arrays with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have learned how to combine 2 arrays, so I made the first $array1 that will be the names of loop fields and the 2nd $array2  will be the values of field it selft, as following

```
$array1 = array ( Field One, Field Two, Field Three );
```

then the 2nd Array derived from mysql table e.g.

```
$array2 = $conn->db_FetchResult("SELECT id FROM %sfields ...);
```

the result view of ***$array2*** such as

```
$array2 = array (field_1 => '1', field_2 => '2', field_3 => '3' );
```

how to combine both those arrays?

**Expected output:**

```
$array3 = array (Field One => '1', Field Two => '2', Field Three => '3' );
```

I have Tried use array_combine, array_merge

> print_r(array_combine($array1,$array2) as $array => $value);

but can not acomplish it,
I have not found the exact same example, there might be willing to help, thanks

Comment: Most likely `$array2` is going to be multi-dimensional so you need to loop it.

Comment: sure, i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/769631)

```
<?php
$array1 = array ( "Field One", "Field Two", "Field Three" );
$array2 = array ("field_1" => '1', "field_2" => '2', "field_3" => '3' );

$c=array_combine($array1,$array2);
print_r($c);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Field One] => 1
    [Field Two] => 2
    [Field Three] => 3
)
```

Comment: thank you @Sahil Gulati, previously unthinkable without: `as $array => $value` but how if `$array1 = array ( "Field One => field_1", "Field Two => field_2", "Field Three => field_3" );` and `$array2 = array ("field_1" => '1', "field_2" => '2', "field_3" => '3' );` Become: `Array ( [Field One] => 1 [Field Two] => 2 [Field Three] => 3 )` ??

Comment: @StarcuteJones Welcome ... :)